# Is f Riemann integrable on $[0,2] $ ? Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Is the function   $f(x)  = \begin{cases} \text{1 if} \ x \neq 1 \\  0\  \text {if x = 1} \end{cases}$ Riemann integrable on $[0,2] $ ?

My attempt :   I  think  No , because  here $L(P,f) \neq U(P,f)$

Is it True?

Comment: By definition $f$ is integrable if $\sup_P L(f,P)=\inf_P U(f,P)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is bounded on $[0,2]$ and continuous on $[0,2] \setminus \{1\}.$ Hence, $f$ is Riemann- integrable.

Answer (score 6):

The function is Riemann integrable. Even though the maximum and minimum in one/two of the intervals in any partition are different,this difference vanishes when you let the lengths of the intervals in the partition tend to $0$.

Comment: thanks u @ Kavi  sir  im not getting how can we  let the length of the  interval in the partion tend to  0  here  im getting  $U(P,f) =  2$ and $L(P,f) =0$   Can u elaborate more ?

Comment: Your calculation of $L(P,f)$ and $U(P,f)$ is wrong. Look at the subintervals which contain the point $x=1$, Note that in all other intervals the max and the min  of the function are equal.

Answer (score 1):

We can show the following: Let $a,b\in\mathbb R,a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ Riemann-integrable. Let $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $M=\{x\in[a,b];f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is finite. Then $g$ is Riemann-integrable with $\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. (Notice that we do not need $f$ or $g$ to be continuous).

Proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$ und $I=\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, then there exist step-functions $\varphi,\psi:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that
$$\varphi\leq f\leq\psi,~I-\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq\varepsilon,~\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-I\leq\varepsilon$$
We define 
$$\varphi^*(x)=\begin{cases} g(x), & x\in M \\ \varphi(x), & x\notin M\end{cases},\quad \psi^*(x)=\begin{cases} g(x),&x\in M \\ \psi(x),&x\notin M\end{cases}.$$
Because $M$ is finite these are again step-functions and we can easily see that
$$\varphi^*\leq g \leq \psi^*,~ \int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\varphi^*(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,~\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!\psi^*(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
Therefore we have
$$I-\int\limits_{a}^{b}\varphi^*(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq \varepsilon,\quad \int\limits_{a}^{b}\psi^*(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-I\leq\varepsilon$$
from which we conclude that $g$ is Riemann-integrable with $\int\limits_{a}^{b}\!g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=I$.