# Is $f(x)$ Riemann integrable on $[0,2]?$ Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let $f : [0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \ \text{ if } x \in [0,1) \\ \frac{1}{2} \ \text{ if } x=1  \\ 0  \ \text{ if } x \in (1,2] \end{cases}$

My  question : Is $f(x)$  Riemann integrable on $[0,2]?$

My attempt : I think **NO**

Take partiton $P= \{0 <1-\epsilon , 1+\epsilon  <2\}$ then we have

$L(f,P) =1-\epsilon$ and $ U(f,P)=1 +\epsilon$

$\implies  U(f,P) - L(f,P) =1+ \epsilon- 1 + \epsilon= 2 \epsilon  > \epsilon$

This leads to the contradiction
because for riemann integral we must have $$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$$

Comment: **Riemann** please!!!

Comment: @MartinR i edited

Comment: Hey, then take another partition like $\{0,1-\frac{\varepsilon}{4},1+\frac{\varepsilon}{4},2\}$. The function is Riemann integrable

Comment: All piecewise continuous functions are Riemann integrable, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350326/42969.

Comment: $f$ has a countable set of discontinuities. It will be integrable. The idea behind showing it in integrable using sums of patitions is that you can make the interval small enough that the "rectangle'' at the discontinuity is arbitrarily small.

Comment: @jasmine FYI, this question (and the solution methods) is very similar to your question of [Is f Riemann integrable on $[0,2] $ ? Yes/No](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275898/602049) from about $2$ and a half years ago, with the main difference being the value of $f(x)$ is the same on either side of $x = 1$ there but not here.

Comment: For $\epsilon  > 0$ you have found *some partition* such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) > \epsilon$. Do you see where the flaw in your argument is?

Comment: @MartinR Here $U(f,P) =\sum \max f(x)$ and $ L(f,P)= \sum \min f(x)$ where $x \in [1-\epsilon, 1 +\epsilon]$

Comment: You've concluded that with your specific partition, U - L = 2ε. This demonstrates that the difference can be made arbitrarily small (the quantity 2ε can be made small by choosing ε even smaller), so the correct conclusion is that the function *is* integrable. Indeed, try repeating your argument with the letter δ instead of ε, then at the top say "let δ < ε/2" to see that $U(f, P_\delta) - L(f, P_\delta) = 2\delta < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @RobBland: That's pretty close to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**:- If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded on $[a.b]$ and is continuous on $[a,b]$ except for a finite number of points . Then $f$ is Riemann Integrable. (More generally if the derived set of the set of discontinuities is finite , then also the function is Riemann integrable. More generally if the set of discontinuities is a set of measure zero. Then the function is Riemann integrable.)

For a proof.Try and enclose the points of discontinuity by non overlapping subintervals whose lenght is lesser than a given epsilon and cover the rest intervals by partitions such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\leq \epsilon$. This is possible as in the rest of those intervals f is continuious and hence Riemann integrable.
This will give you the required partition of the set $[a,b]$.